# Merge two incomplete backup volumes together on a third drive?

Tags: windows-7, backup, storage, comparison

I have 2 drives that use to be backed up to each other (a 2TB drive to a 3TB drive) but they fell out of sync a long time ago. Files on the drives may not be located in the folders they use to share, and this updating goes both ways. However, I recently purchased a new drive (4TB) where I want to create a master volume to back up both to. How can I effectively figure out duplicate files even if they dont share directories, so that I copy only unique files to this new drive?

Comment: Lookup FreeFileSync